# Show $A-K$ has closed range, where $A$ is a continuous bijection and $K$ is compact.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

**Problem**

> > Let $X$ be a Hilbert space, $A:X \rightarrow X$ a continuous linear bijection, $K:X \rightarrow X$ a compact linear operator. Prove that $A-K$ has closed range.

**Attempt**

First I showed that $I-K$ has closed range. Then I proceeded as follows:

If $A$ is a linear bijection, then $A^{-1}$ is continuous by the open mapping theorem. Thus $A^{-1}K$ is compact. Consequently
$$(I-A^{-1}K)$$ has closed range. If $v_n \rightarrow v$ and $v_n \in \mathrm{Range}(A-K)$ then I must show that $v\in \mathrm{Range}(A-K)$. By assumption there exist $u_n$ such that $$v_n=(A-K)u_n=A(I-A^{-1}K)u_n.$$ Thus $A^{-1}v_n=(I-A^{-1}K)u_k$. So by continuity, $A^{-1}v_n\rightarrow A^{-1}v$ and due to $\mathrm{Range}(I-A^{-1}K)$ being closed, $A^{-1}v\in \mathrm{Range}(I-A^{-1}K)$, Thus $$v=(A-K)u$$ for some $u$.

Comment: What's the question? Are you looking for a proof verification?

Comment: @Aweygan yes I was looking for proof verification. I have updated the tags accordingly.

Comment: @Kenny_Wong I didn't realize that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have identified that $A^{-1}$ is continuous (by the inverse function theorem), so $A^{-1}K$ is compact, so the range of $I - A^{-1}K$ is closed.

Applying (original version of) the open mapping theorem to $A$, you learn that $A$ maps open sets to open sets. Since it is bijective, this means that $A$ maps closed sets to closed sets.

Therefore, the range of $A - K = A(I - A^{-1}K)$ is closed.

Comment: Hang on, before you accept this, are you sure $A^{-1}K$ is compact?

Comment: (see Aweygan's answer)

Comment: Both are compact.  The collection of compact operators forms an ideal.

Comment: Oh yes, of course.

Comment: Still I think the OP should accept Aweygan's answer because it's neater!

Comment: I appreciate the kind words but that is, just as the OP's acceptance, is an opinion.

Comment: @KennyWong I accepted your answer because you commented with it  first As soon as you made the comment, I understood what was necessary to complete the argument.

Answer (score 4):

An easier way to show this is observing that $KA^{-1}$ is compact, so $I-KA^{-1}$ has closed range. Now we have
$$\text{Ran}(A-K)=\text{Ran}((I-KA^{-1})A)=\text{Ran}(I-KA^{-1})$$
(the last equality comes from $A$ being a bijection) and thus $A-K$ has closed range.